# Как оставлять прежнее значение поля в UPDATE при передаче NULL?

Tags: c#, sql, .net, sql-server

В UPDATE передаю 7 параметров. Произвольное количество которых может быть null. Как построить SQL запрос таким образом, чтобы в случае значения переменной null оставалось старое значение в бд?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Можно воспользоваться функцией `COALESCE` и тем фактом, что выполнение `Value = Value` в `UPDATE` оставляет прежнее значение:

```
UPDATE FooTable
SET BarColumn = COALESCE(@BarColumn, BarColumn)
```

Answer (score 5):

```
UPDATE ...
SET SomeColumn = COALESCE(@NewValue, SomeColumn)
```